# Apache Ant issue with adding External Jars

Tags: java, ant

I can run at compile time but when I attempt to jar it always gives me this error. I'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openpgp/operator/KeyFingerPrintCalculator
```

This is what my manifest looks like

```
Main-Class: com.Program
Class-Path: extlib/bcpg-jdk14-156.jar extlib/bcprov-jdk14-156.jar extlib/commons-io-2.5.jar
```

Here is my build.xml

```
<manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="Program.jar">
 <classpath>
    <fileset dir = "./${extlib}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
 </classpath>
</manifestclasspath>
```

And here is the jar code

```
 <jar jarfile="${dist}/Program.jar" basedir="${build}">
    <manifest>
       <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.Program"/>
       <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
    </manifest>
 </jar>
```

This is what my file structure looks like

```
Program.jar
extlib\bcpg-jdk14-156.jar
extlib\bcprov-jdk14-156.jar
extlib\commons-io-2.5.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated been banging my head for 2 days now. If you need anymore info just let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that missing class is in one of those jar files?

Comment: Yes, when I take them out of my extlib directory on compile time the program throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

- Unsigning the jar files seemed to work.
- Open the bouncycastle jar files, delete the META-INF folder, then rejar and rerun ant jar for PrintProcessor.

Good luck!
-Ethan